# アプリ広告の表示方法について

Tags: android, ios

お世話になっております。

現在アプリに広告をつけようと思っているのですが、広告の表示方法について質問があります。

下記画像のタグ？がPRとなっているリストの項目があるのですが、それをタップすると広告
になっており、AppStore等に遷移します。
そこで質問なのですが、
このようなコンテンツに紛れた？ような広告を出す方法としてはどのような方法があるのでしょうか？

[image: 広告参考]

Comment: 具体的に何がわからないのかが見えないのですが、「PR記事を他の記事に混ぜて一覧表示する」「PR記事だけタップ時のアクションを別にする」「AppStoreへの遷移」のどれのことを指していますか？

Comment: 分かりにくくて申し訳ありません。
「PR記事を他の記事に混ぜて一覧表示する」です。
パッと見、コンテンツのように見えるように広告を表示しているのですが、どのように広告を組み込むのがいいのかと思い質問させて頂きました。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

上の例は、iPadのUISplitViewControllerをつかったものですが、そのなかで、UITableViewControllerを使って有ります。

ふつう、モバイル広告のバナー広告は、決められたサイズのバナー表示領域を使うわけですが、
UITableViewDataSourceプロトコルの
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

にて、indexPath.row % 10 ==0 なら、広告表示が張り付いたContentViewのセルを返し
indexPath.row % 10 !=0 なら、ニュース文字列をつかって、セルを返す。

UITableViewは、セルさえ作ってくれれば、テーブル表示の職人ですから、ちゃんと表示してくれると思いますけど。